# Django, MySQL, and SSL certs: strings instead of filenames?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm attempting to configure a Django application to connect to a MySQLDB instance with TLS configured.

Django's DATABASES settings documents how to configure the `ssl` settings, for eg.:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE':   os.environ.get('DATABASE_ENGINE', 'django.db.backends.mysql'),
        'HOST':     os.environ.get('DATABASE_HOST'),
        'PASSWORD': get_vault_secret('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
...

        'OPTIONS': {
            'ssl': {
                'ca': '/ca/server.cert.pem',
                'cert': '/ca/client.cert.pem',
                'key': '/ca/client.key.pem'
            }
        }
    },
}
```

Our problem is that the values required for `ca`, `cert`, and `key` are filenames. Our app is containerized, and we pull all of our secrets from hashicorp Vault during app initialization using a helper func (see the value for PASSWORD).

We also store client certs, keys, etc in vault, and would like to supply these to Django directly - but MySQL demands a string, pointing to a file.

Is there a way to wrap the cert / ca / key strings we get from vault into some kind of `IOFile` / `BytesIO` esque container to pass from Django, to python mysqlclient, to `mysql_ssl_set()`?

Due to security considerations, actually writing these values to a file is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `entrypoint.sh` script for your container which can fetch the files from your vault first and then start the django process. Make sure to add `set -e` to the script so that the container is restarted if the fetch fails. Otherwise you'd just end up with unable to connect errors

Comment: I'm unable to write the secrets to a file.

Comment: What error are you getting on attempting to do so?

Comment: A slack message from our Security Engineers: "Hey, we talked about this, but it looks like you're still writing the private key to file in your container. Are you free for 20m for a quick chat?" :D

Comment: Did you try blocking the security engineer on slack? :P On a serious note, I'm not sure how you can use certificate based TLS while having the certificate files in the container. Django's SQL ORM or MySQLdb package (used by the ORM) doesn't support key vault based secrets to the best of my knowledge :/